# Work done and deriving elastic collisions

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, collision

Using Newton's second law, it is possible to write the work done on a path going from position A to B as:

$$W_{AB}=\int^B_Am\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}\cdot d\vec{r} =m\int^B_A(\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}\cdot \vec{v})dt=\frac{1}{2}m\int^B_A\frac{d}{dt}(v^2)dt $$

I would be very grateful if someone might explain where the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ arise from. I understand that $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}=cos\theta|\vec{v}||\vec{v}|$ but don't know why/if theta must 60 degrees (thus $cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}$).

Comment: This is just product rule of differentation.

Comment: @FredericThomas I'd be really appreciative if you might explain further?

Comment: $0.5(v^2)' =0.5( vv' + v'v) = vv'$

Comment: $\int v {\rm d}v = \tfrac{1}{2} v^2$ or in reverse $$\tfrac{1}{2} \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} v^2 = v \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} v $$

Answer (score 0):

${d \over dt}v^2 = {d \over dt} (\vec v \cdot { \vec v)} = {d \vec v \over dt} \cdot \vec v + \vec v \cdot  {d \vec v \over dt} = 2\vec v \cdot {d \vec v \over dt}$